# Preg Match to find count of exact word in string

Tags: php, regex

I want to find the number of words in a string. I used the below regex to do the same.

```
$count_keys = preg_match_all('/\bs.c.\b/', $str);
```

Here $str is the string from which we **need to found the number of occurance of the word s.c** , But i am getting wrong result say if their is a word #ssc or #sssc they are also counted as well. Please guide me where I am doing the mistake or please give the correct regex code to do the same.

Comment: escape `.` as  `s\.c`...In PHP `s\\.c`

Comment: use `(\bs\.c)` only.

Comment: You are counting `s.c.` or `s.c` ?

Comment: It is unclear: in code, your pattern has a `.` after `s.c`, but then, *occurance of the word **s.c*** follows.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, He mention it: `need to found the number of occurance of the word s.c`

Comment: @FrayneKonok: Then why is the regex `\bs.c.\b`?

Comment: that is his typing / thinking mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$str = 'this is a s.c good to check s.c ';

echo $count_keys = preg_match_all('/\bs\.c/', $str);
```

**Output:**

> 2

Comment: Thanks a lot Frayne Konok

Comment: This answer doesn't fully explain what was wrong with the OP's regular expression. Also, this regex would match "s.cc", "s.cs", "s.cssc" etc.

Answer (score 0):

use substr_count() instead of preg_match_all

[this is the tutorials](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
<?php
$text = 'This is a test';
echo strlen($text); // 14

echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2

// the string is reduced to 's is a test', so it prints 1
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3);

// the text is reduced to 's i', so it prints 0
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 3, 3);

// generates a warning because 5+10 > 14
echo substr_count($text, 'is', 5, 10);


// prints only 1, because it doesn't count overlapped substrings
$text2 = 'gcdgcdgcd';
echo substr_count($text2, 'gcdgcd');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your regular expression. If you are looking for occurrences of "s.c" try this:

```
$count_keys = preg_match_all('/\bs\.c\b/', $str);
```

You were missing a "\" before the "." which caused a problem because "." matches any character (except newlines) in regular expressions.

However, if you are looking for occurrences of "s.c." then try this:

```
$count_keys = preg_match_all('/\bs\.c\.\b/', $str);
```

Comment: The only problem is that we do not know if OP searches for `s.c.` or `s.c`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, He mention it: `need to found the number of occurance of the word s.c`

Comment: But OP regex includes a dot after `c` - it is suspicious.